# Trying to load icons from method that returns Bitmap to google map

Tags: flutter

I am trying to load dynamically icons on google map, the below example works fine. However when Im trying to run it as a method that returns BitMapDescriptor then I am facing this error:
`Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'BitmapDescriptor'` Any ways I can fix this?

This works:

```dart
  void customMarker(int index) {
    BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(ImageConfiguration(size: Size(20, 20)),
        'assets/images/route_markers/$index.png')
        .then((res) {
      _pinLocationIcon = res;
    });

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    customMarker(1);
    getCurrentLocation();
  }

and put _pinLocationIcon  as an icon in loop.
```

Doesn't work :

```dart
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      final marker = Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(markers[i].id),
        position: 53, 22),
        icon: customMarker(i),
        onTap: () {},

      );
}

  BitmapDescriptor customMarker(int index) {
    var data;
    BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(ImageConfiguration(size: Size(20, 20)),
        'assets/images/items/$index.png')
        .then((res) {
      data = res;
    });

    return data;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage` is asynchronous, that's why you are calling`.then` on the method, it means that the value can be returned at any time, not in the order of the code written.
The code inside `then((res){...` will set the value for the variable `data` after `data` was already returned with a null value, so you won't get your icon.

You need to learn how to use asynchronous methods, in this case, you would need to make those methods `async`, and `await` for the image to load before returning. Try this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  loadMarkers();
  getCurrentLocation();
}

void loadMarkers() async { // Notice the async keyword
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

    final marker = Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(markers[i].id),
      position: 53, 22),
      icon: await customMarker(i), //Notice the await here
      onTap: () {},
    );
  }
}

BitmapDescriptor customMarker(int index) async { //Notice Async and Await again
  var data = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
     ImageConfiguration(size: Size(20, 20)),
     'assets/images/items/$index.png'
  );
  return data;
}
```